# Projectivization in the derived category of coherent sheaves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, derived-categories, projective-geometry, coherent-sheaves

Let $X$ be a compact Kahler manifold. There exists a notion of projectivization of holomorphic vector bundles and coherent sheaves over $X$. Does that concept extend to objects in the derived category $D^bCoh(X)$ ? In particular is there a notion of projectivization of complexes of vector bundles?

Comment: Hmm, there is a problem that a linear map $f \colon V \to W$ does not induce a morphism $\mathbf P(f) \colon \mathbf P(V) \to \mathbf P(W)$, unless $f$ is *injective*. In general you only get a *rational map* $\mathbf P(V) \dashrightarrow \mathbf P(W)$.

Comment: Do you have an idea what sort of thing you're looking for if $X$ is a point?

Comment: In the algebraic case at least there is such a notion, which outputs derived schemes/stacks. Given a connective object of the derived category, you can take Spec of the symmetric algebra on it, which is a derived scheme with an action of $\mathbb A^1$, remove the zero section and quotient by the action of $\mathbb G_m$. If the object is not connective one cannot just take Spec, but IIRC one can show that the functor represented by the symmetric algebra is a derived Artin stack.

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn unfortunately I don't. More than that, I dont know what the projectivization of a Z-graded vector space is